# Spring integration JDBCMessageHandler error handling strategy

Tags: spring-integration

There appear to be multiple prior questions about this, mostly with cold links to the old Spring forums.

Here is the subflow I am trying to capture exceptions/errors from:

```
        return flowDef
            .filter(getFilterExpression(rule)).channel(new DirectChannel())
            .handle(inboundAdapter)
            .split(insertDeleteSplitter)
            .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> 
                    c.subscribe(s -> s
                        .filter ("....")
                        .transform(genericTransformer)
                        .handle(insertUpdateMessageHandler(rule))) // a JDBCMessageHandler
                    .subscribe(s -> s
                        .filter("....")
                        .transform(genericTransformer)
                        .handle(deleteMessageHandler(rule))) // a JDBCMessageHandler
                    .subscribe(sub -> sub
                        .handle(cleanupMessageHandler(rule))) // a JDBCMessageHandler
//                  .errorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler()); // Obviously not working
            );
```

The symptom I am seeing is that the errors are propagated back to the poller, which does not have the detail necessary to resolve the issues.

My intent is that any exceptions or errors will be caught and rerouted from this subflow level, where the message is complete, to an error flow that consists of code to record the failure and core data then completes cleanup.

- Starting condition: Message ABC has been properly routed to this subflow
- Message ABC has been split and routed to (example) the insertUpdateMessageHandler (JDBCMessageHandler)
- Handling fails - Database server throws duplicate row (for example)

**Actual outcome:**

- Exception is caught by the poller, which does not have the necessary information to record/handle the error

**Desired outcome:**

- Exception is handled at this level, and the flow ends.

**My suspicisons:**

- Ideally, I've made a simple typo and will feel like a fool when it's pointed out
- I suspect that this is a design consideration, with the intent that the Poller be the level at which errors or handled, probably for transactionality.
- I may need to build my exception handling into custom message handlers that wrap the JDBC message handler then handle the exceptions

---

(Edit)
See also: [How do I configure this JdbcMessageHandler to pull parameters from the message instead of static beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69844576/how-do-i-configure-this-jdbcmessagehandler-to-pull-parameters-from-the-message-i)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "the poller does not have the necessary information...".

You can add an `errorChannel` to the poller and the downstream flow from that channel will get an `ErrorMessage` with a payload of type `MessagingException` with `failedMessage` and `cause` properties. The `ErrorMessage` also has the original message property.

Alternatively, you can add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the adapter endpoint's advice chain.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice

Comment: `.handle(inboundAdapter)` - I hope it is not a `MessageSource` and really some service method to accept a message and produce some reply. The `inboundAdapter` name is usually used for the beginning of the flow with a poller: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound

Comment: `.errorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler()); // Obviously not working` - I think we need to improve JavaDocs on the `PublishSubscribeChannelSpec.errorHandler()`. See the target `PublishSubscribeChannel.setErrorHandler()` JavaDocs:  `This will only be applied if an Executor has been configured to dispatch the Messages for this channel.`

Comment: Here is the declaration for inboundAdapter:   final JdbcOutboundGateway inboundAdapter = createInboundAdapter(rule); When this subflow is kicked off from the poller, it has enough information to pull the requested data from the source database.  The poller at the root of the main flow fetches a minimal amount of metadata then splits to each of the subflows

Comment: It looks like the correct fix may have been to add a TaskExecutor to the PubSub channel in the subflow (plus a misplaced semicolon).  I'm having difficulty testing because the cleanup step is blowing up deep in the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate - for another question

Comment: With the task executor added, the error handler is invoked properly.  However, the odds are 50/50 that the cleanupMessageHandler is invoked before the message is handled. Since the data is all in the message at this point, and the message is persisted for future use by the error handler, I am trying to decide whether or not this is a good thing. Since the JdbcMessageHandler issues a reply message with only an arrayList of 0 (fail) or 1 (success) elements, per submitted row, I can't just inline the cleanup with that, and a wireTap interferes with error handling.