# How do I configure this JdbcMessageHandler to pull parameters from the message instead of static beans?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

**The Symptom:**

When invoked, the `cleanupMessageHandler` component (a JdbcMessageHandler) of this subflow is not pulling parameters from the message, but is instead attempting to pull from a static bean.

**The exception message:**

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'ALC_startTime': Invalid property 'ALC_startTime' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler$1]: Bean property 'ALC_startTime' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

**The SQL**

```
Delete from SB_STREAM.TT_9321383 
WHERE (LASTUPDATESTAMP >= to_timestamp (:ALC_startTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
    and LASTUPDATESTAMP <= to_timestamp (:ALC_endTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) 
AND ttkey = BIGINT(:ID) 
AND (ttobjectname = :ALC_object AND ttschema = :ALC_schema)
```

**The Flow:**

```
   return flowDef
        .filter(getFilterExpression(rule)).channel(new DirectChannel())
        .handle(inboundAdapter) // a JdbcOutboundAdapter
        .split(insertDeleteSplitter)
        .publishSubscribeChannel(taskExecutor, c -> 
                c.subscribe(s -> s
                    .filter ("....")
                    .transform(genericTransformer)
                    .handle(insertUpdateMessageHandler(rule))) // a JDBCMessageHandler
                .subscribe(s -> s
                    .filter("....")
                    .transform(genericTransformer)
                    .handle(deleteMessageHandler(rule))) // a JDBCMessageHandler
                .subscribe(sub -> sub
                    .handle(cleanupMessageHandler(rule))) // a JDBCMessageHandler
              .errorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler() // 
        );
```

**The cleanupMessagehandler**

```
private MessageHandler cleanupMessageHandler(RuleMetadata rule) {

<snip ...>
    SQLTextAndParamsList sql = sqlFactory.getCleanupSQL(rule);
    JdbcMessageHandler handler = new JdbcMessageHandler(dbprx.getDatasource(), sql.getSql());

    return handler;
}
```

**Message as received by JdbcMessageHandler**
[image: Message as received by JdbcMessageHandler]

**SQLParameterSources at point where JDBCOperation is invoked**
[image: SQLParameterSources at point where JDBCOperation is invoked]

**Alternate coding - batchArray of values at JDBCOperation is invoked (added ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory to the JdbcMessageHandler)**
[image]

**Debugger view at AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue()**
[image: Debugger view at AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue()]

**Debugger view at CachedIntrospectionResults.getPropertyDecriptor()**
[image]

---

**Edit: code changes**

The generated SQL was updated to this:

```
Delete from SB_STREAM.TT_9321383 
WHERE (LASTUPDATESTAMP >= to_timestamp (:payload[ALC_startTime], 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
    and LASTUPDATESTAMP <= to_timestamp (:payload[ALC_endTime], 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) 
AND ttkey = :payload[ID] 
AND (ttobjectname = :payload[ALC_object] AND ttschema = :payload[ALC_schema])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your first screenshot, the payload of your message is an `ArrayList`, which indeed does not have those `ALC_startTime`, `ALC_endTime` properties. There are just no those getters on the `ArrayList`!

To be able to read a content of your list, you need to configure an `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` on your `JdbcMessageHandler`. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#passing-parameters-by-using-spel-expressions.

Probably better to convert your list into a `Map` somehow or some POJO representation. With the list it is going to be hard for your to determine the target value by just index...

---

**Edit:**
This is a batch update, so the array list of maps is correct.

The SPEl expressions in the SQL parameters are malformed.  The correct form is `:payload[ALC_startTime]`.

Comment: The payload is an ArrayList of Maps.  You can see what happens when a ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory is applied to this in the final screenshot. Since the target platform for the process is entirely dynamic (i.e. I may never know what customers point it at) I can't really create POJO's.  The payload needs to be Maps.

Comment: maps work everywhere else in the product with no intervention

Comment: Oh! I see it is a `batchUpdate()`. So, yes then `BeanPropertySqlParameterSourceFactory` should work against the `Map`. If you can debug it, please, follow the break point in the `StaticBeanPropertySqlParameterSource.hasValue()` to see how it tries to resolve your param against the actual `Map` from your list.

Comment: The code does not appear to enter the hasValue() method, but instead goes directly to getValue(). Since there is no PropertyHandler assigned, it immediately throws an exception.

Comment: What is that `actualName` and what is going on when it tries to resolve that property handler? Can you debug it deeper ?

Comment: actualName is ALC_startTime. In CachedIntrospectionResult, the propertyDescriptors map contains descriptors for class, headers, and payload (not for the actual contents of the payload.

Comment: Ok. Do it like this `:payload.ALC_startTime` then in the query!

Comment: The contents of the parameter array generated are correct, but NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray throws an InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException "No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'payload.ALC_startTime': Invalid property 'payload.ALC_startTime' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler$1]: Bean property 'payload.ALC_startTime' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"

Comment: Hm. How about `:payload[ALC_startTime]` then? That's what I see in our tests `JdbcMessageHandler handler = new JdbcMessageHandler(jdbcTemplate, "insert into foos (id, status, name) values (:headers[business.id], 0, :payload)");` where `headers` is indeed a `Map`.

Comment: That looks healthier.  Moving on to the next problem.